# Amqpcpp undefined symbol

Tags: c++, amqp

I'm triying to run one of the examples from `amqpcpp` (code snippet):

```
int onCancel(AMQPMessage * message ) { 
   AMQPQueue * q = message->getQueue();
   q->Cancel( message->getConsumerTag());
   return 0;
}
```

I have the following error:

> undefined symbol: _ZN11AMQPMessage8getQueueEv

I have included the header file of `amqpcpp`. According this, other objects from this header are identified and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The error is actually a *linker* error, and means you didn't link with the AMQP library. Add the library to your list of libraries in the project settings (if you're using an IDE) or add `-lamqpcpp` to the command line (optionally you need `-L<path to amqpcpp library>` if you have installed it in a non-standard directory).

Comment: Joachim, it's already included `-lamqpcpp` in command line (into the makfile file). But, In my opinion, this error is produced in runtime not in compiling or linking steps.

Comment: @user2788018 So the program builds properly? There is an executable? That you can manually run? And when you do it produces this error?

Comment: Right. Builds properly and when i run it manually, the error appears.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party but I was having the same problem. I linked AMQP-CPP to my program using a CMake file but CMake complained that it wasn't there. Apparently the order of the libraries matter. Since one depended on another it couldn't compile. Me moving the AMQP-CPP as the last library fixed the problem.